# array insert to database start from "0"

Tags: php, arrays

i got array like this :

```
$arr =  Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 )
```

so, this array named "aspek_a",
i want this "aspek_a" insert to database but when i submit, the problem is, values start from 0 not from 1, because value of aspek_a is start from 1.

this is my code when input to database:

```
if (isset($_POST['cmdSubmitAspek'])) 
{
$nilaiBobot = $_POST['nilaiBobot']; 
$aspek_aTemp = $_POST['aspek_a']; 


$multi = new MultipleIterator();
$multi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($nilaiBobot));
$multi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($aspek_aTemp));

foreach($multi as $key => $value){

 list($nilaiBobot, $aspek_aTemp) = $multi->key();
 list($nilaiBobot, $aspek_a) = $value;

$queryInsAspek = "insert into skalaPrioritas (idDivisi, idDepartment, aspek, nilaiBobot, submitBy, inputDT)
              VALUES  (".$idDivisi.", ".$idDepartment.", '". $aspek_aTemp."','".$nilaiBobot."',".$userID.", getdate())";
```

this named in html for aspek_a :

```
echo "<td class='custGanjil300b border1'> $aspek_a[$i] <input type='hidden' name='aspek_a[".$i."]'  value='".$aspek_a[$i]."' ></td>";
```

and this is result when i'm submit :

```
insert into skalaPrioritas (idDivisi, idDepartment, aspek, nilaiBobot, submitBy, inputDT) VALUES (1, 9, '0','80',371, getdate())
insert into skalaPrioritas (idDivisi, idDepartment, aspek, nilaiBobot, submitBy, inputDT) VALUES (1, 9, '1','',371, getdate())
insert into skalaPrioritas (idDivisi, idDepartment, aspek, nilaiBobot, submitBy, inputDT) VALUES (1, 9, '2','',371, getdate())
insert into skalaPrioritas (idDivisi, idDepartment, aspek, nilaiBobot, submitBy, inputDT) VALUES (1, 9, '3','',371, getdate())
insert into skalaPrioritas (idDivisi, idDepartment, aspek, nilaiBobot, submitBy, inputDT) VALUES (1, 9, '4','',371, getdate())
insert into skalaPrioritas (idDivisi, idDepartment, aspek, nilaiBobot, submitBy, inputDT) VALUES (1, 9, '5','',371, getdate())
insert into skalaPrioritas (idDivisi, idDepartment, aspek, nilaiBobot, submitBy, inputDT) VALUES (1, 9, '6','',371, getdate())
insert into skalaPrioritas (idDivisi, idDepartment, aspek, nilaiBobot, submitBy, inputDT) VALUES (1, 9, '7','',371, getdate())
insert into skalaPrioritas (idDivisi, idDepartment, aspek, nilaiBobot, submitBy, inputDT) VALUES (1, 9, '8','',371, getdate())
insert into skalaPrioritas (idDivisi, idDepartment, aspek, nilaiBobot, submitBy, inputDT) VALUES (1, 9, '9','',371, getdate())
```

please help me to this right,
and sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: Your query has `$aspek_aTemp`, shouldn't it be `$aspek_a`?

Comment: yes, but if i make all the aspek_aTemp to aspek_a value in the query insert of  column aspek is empty

insert into skalaPrioritas (idDivisi, idDepartment, aspek, nilaiBobot, submitBy, inputDT) VALUES (1, 9, '','80',371, getdate())

Comment: But `$aspek_aTemp` is the key, which is why it goes from 0-9 instead of 1-10. So you need to figure out why `$aspek_a` is empty because your code is fine otherwise